# parameterisation for curver C interms of single increasing variable t

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm struggling on parameterisation curves,
C is a curve along intersection of 2 surfaces, 
$z=x^4+y+1$ and $y=3$, from point$(1,3,5)$ to $(-2,3,20)$

I have to find a parameterisation for curver C  interms of single increasing variable t.

I tried $x(t)=t$  ,  $y(t)=3$  , $z(t)=t^4+4$ for $ -2\leq t \leq 1$
But it doesn't seem right.

I don't really understand when to use $x(t)=x0+(x1-x0)t$, and when to use $x(t)=t$

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is correct: just check that any parametrized vector $\;(t,\,3,\,t^4+1)\;$ is in both surfaces. I don't understand your second question. It seems to be you mean something like a straight line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that the parameter $t$ stays in the interval $ [0,1]$ than you have to use the parametrization $x=x_0+t(x_1-x_0)$, that in this case becomes:
$
x=1-3t
$
 so that for $z$ you have $z=(1-3t)^4+4$.

Comment: Hi, can there be multiple parameterisation for this problem? Like,$x=1-3t z=(1-3t)^4+4$ for $ 0 \leq t \leq 1$, and also $x=t, z=t^4+4 $, for t from 1 to -2, thank you

Comment: the questions says "interms of single increasing variable t." does that mean $x=t,z=t^4+4$ for t over interval  [1,-2] in not vaild because t is decreasing?

Comment: If the parameter $t$ has to be increasing from $x=1$ to $x=-2$, than $x=t$ for $t \in [1,-2]$ is not valid. We can chose $x=-t$ for $t \in [-1,2]$ and this is one (many) possible parameterisations. In my answer I prefer a ''standard'' interval $t \in [0,1]$, also because this seams suggested in OP.